# Передать параметры из C# в библиотеку C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll

На C# написана программа, есть там тип данных `List<Tuple<double,double,DateTime>>`, необходимо это передать во встраиваемую библиотеку С++. Kак в С++ именно записать вводные данные? Kаким типом? Скорее всего буду хранить их в массиве структур. Но как провести передачу именно? Библиотеку на С++ буду писать сам. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: так а какой тип принимаемого значения у метода в c++ библиотеке?

Comment: @yolosora библиотека моя, я пока еще не реализовал её. Не знаю, как перевести мой тип на C# в тип массив структур.

Comment: От кортежа лучше отказаться. Использовать структуру. Использовать [маршаллинг](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже подсказали в комментах, удобне будет использовать структуру. `DateTime` лучше не передавать в C++ напрямую, а превратить его в что-то иное. Вот пример.

C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Data
{
    public double d1;
    public double d2;
    public int year;
    public int month;
    public int day;
}

[DllImport("CppDll")]
public static extern bool MyCppFunc(int count, Data[] data);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Data> list = new List<Data>
    {
        new Data
        {
            d1 = 123,
            d2 = 0.5,
            year = 2018,
            month = 3,
            day = 12
        },
        new Data
        {
            d1 = 456,
            d2 = 0.75,
            year = 2018,
            month = 3,
            day = 15
        },
    };
    MyCppFunc(list.Count, list.ToArray());
}
```

C++:

```
typedef struct _MYDATA
{
    double d1;
    double d2;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
} MYDATA;

BOOL WINAPI MyCppFunc(int count, MYDATA * data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("d1=%f\n", data[i].d1);
        printf("d2=%f\n", data[i].d2);
        printf("year=%d\n", data[i].year);
        printf("month=%d\n", data[i].month);
        printf("day=%d\n\n", data[i].day);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример, но при запуске пишет - Не удается найти точку входа "MyCppFunc" в DLL "CppDll"

Comment: Это не полный пример, вам нужно сделать функцию MyCppFunc экспортируемой. Я использовал .def файл.